# Hibernate-Search 6 and Elasticsearch integration

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am working ina Hibernate Search application and I am trying to use version 6 (which right now is in beta). I followed all the instructions and documentation in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started-configuration

After trying to start my application I get next error:

I have looked in Google and seems to be I am the first person in the world who is facing this issue.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.mapping.impl.HibernateOrmIndexedTypeContext.<init>(HibernateOrmIndexedTypeContext.java:35)

The following method did not exist:

    org.hibernate.metamodel.spi.MetamodelImplementor.entity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/metamodel/model/domain/spi/EntityTypeDescriptor;

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/home/myUser/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.metamodel.spi.MetamodelImplementor
```

Any idea of how to solve it?, In my application I am working with Spring boot and jpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated [here in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started-compatibility), Hibernate Search 6.0.0.Beta2 requires Hibernate ORM 5.4.7.Final or later. You are using Hibernate ORM 5.3.11.Final.

I think Spring Boot 2.1 ships with ORM 5.3, so that's probably what you're using.

The best course of action would be to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE, which ships with Hibernate ORM 5.4.

If that's not possible, you can still stay with Spring Boot 2.1 and override the version of Hibernate ORM directly in your POM: from what I've seen, it works rather well in Spring Boot 2.1.

Just set this property in your POM:

```
    <properties>
        <!-- Override the version of Hibernate ORM in Spring Boot -->
        <hibernate.version>5.4.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
```

Note that technically, any version after Hibernate ORM 5.4.4.Final should work, but sticking to the version Hibernate Search was tested with is usually safer.

Comment: thanks it worked for me, Do you know if in Hibernate Search 6 is there something similar to "@IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)", this instruction is from HS5 but does not exist anumore in HS6.

Comment: @alexcornejo Not yet, no: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3071.  You can get a similar behavior by annotating the embedded class's ID with `@GenericField`.